# WPF Close UserControl in Frame and access Parent Controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF app with a Window (RootWindow) with a Toolbar and a Frame (ContentFrame). Initially the Toolbar is hidden.

I load a Login UserControl into the Frame and when the user correctly logs in I'd like to close the UserControl and then make the Parent Window toolbar visible.

Seems such a simple thing to do.

However, you cannot close a UserControl from within the UserControl. So how do I break out of the UserControl so I can remove it from the RootWindow (ContentFrame.Source=Nothing) and also make the toolbar Visible.

I can get a handle for the Parent Window with the following code but I cannot access the controls within it

```
Dim parentWindow As Window = Window.GetWindow(Me) 'Get a handle for parent window
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to access Parent Window Controls from within a Child UserControl or at least be able to Trigger an event in the Parent Window from the Child UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

To find the parent in the hirearchy you can use this code:
http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/detecting-double-click-events-on-the-wpf-datagrid

Although the problem solved in above article is for DataGrid, the code to find parent is generic enough and should work in your case.